# Продление дня - moment js

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, vue.js, typescript

Есть сервис открывающийся и закрывающийся по дням недели (например: пн с 22:00 - 01:20 , вт: c 04:00 - 13:00 , ср: с 17:00 - 21:00 ...).На данный момент мой код работает так что допустим сегодня понедельник и время 23:58 - сервис работает .. время 00:00 сервис не работает и откроется в 04:00..(время с 00:00 до 01:20 не фиксируется т.к. день уже вторник и дата меняется). Мне нужно какое-то решение по флагу, которое не переключит день и продолжит держать сервис открытым до 01:20 и закроется до 04:00

```
    let startTime = moment(foundScheduleItem.open_at, 'HH:mm')
    let endTime = moment(foundScheduleItem.close_at, 'HH:mm')

    const afterStart = moment().isSameOrAfter(startTime)
    const isToday = afterStart && moment().isSameOrAfter(moment('00:00', 'HH:mm'))
    const beforeClose = moment().isSameOrBefore(endTime)

    if (service.extended) { //  extended - флаг
        const checkTodayBeforeMidnight = isToday && afterStart; 

        // If more than 00:00 but less than close time we dont add the day
        if (!beforeClose && checkTodayBeforeMidnight) {
            endTime = moment('23:59', 'HH:mm'); // no work
         } else {
            startTime = moment('00:00', 'HH:mm');
         }
    }
```

Comment: Правильнее всего будет разбить на правильные интервалы.
пн с 22:00 - 24:00, вт: 00:00 - 01:20 , вт: c 04:00 - 13:00 , ср: с 17:00 - 21:00 ...)

Comment: @ВикторКарев правильнее да...) к сожалению возможности по времени сейчас нет менять.. и нужно максимально простое решение, предположительно я бы сделал проверку, и если время закрытия предшествует времени открытия, то переместил бы его на следующий день, но что бы я не писал оно не работает (обновил код в вопросе)

Comment: Разбить на правильные интервалы - это и будет максимально простым решением. Потому что в течение дня может быть несколько рабочих интервалов, - если есть обеденный перерыв, например.